# How to train model with TensorflowSharp

Tags: c#, tensorflow

I am new with TensorfolwSharp.  I see some examples about how to load model and predict using TensorfolwSharp.  But I cannot find examples to train model using TensorfolwSharp.  I give it a try and stuck at Optimizer now.  Too many parameters for ApplyAdam, not even sure this is the right function to use.

Following is my WORKING Tensorflow code.

```
dataX = pd.read_csv('dataX.csv', sep = ',', header = None)
dataX = pd.read_csv('dataY.csv', sep = ',', header = None)  
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, trainX.shape[1]]) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 
W0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([trainX.shape[1], h0size], seed = seed))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h0size], seed = seed))
h = tf.matmul(x, W0) + b0
pred = tf.sigmoid(h)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = h))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(50):
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict ={x: dataX, y: dataX})
```

Following is my attemp to convert to TensorflowSharp

```
        using (var session = new TFSession())
        {
            var graph = session.Graph;
            //dataX = pd.read_csv('dataX.csv', sep = ',', header = None)
            //dataY = pd.read_csv('dataY.csv', sep = ',', header = None)
            float[,] aX = LoadCsv("dataX.csv");
            float[,] aY = LoadCsv("dataY.csv");
            TFTensor dataX = new TFTensor(aX);
            TFTensor dataY = new TFTensor(aY);
            //x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, trainX.shape[1]]) 
            //y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 
            var x = graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.Float, new TFShape(dataX.Shape));
            var y = graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.Float, new TFShape(dataY.Shape));
            var W0 = graph.Variable(graph.RandomNormal(new TFShape(dataX.Shape[1], 1)));
            var b0 = graph.Variable(graph.RandomNormal(new TFShape(1)));
            var h = graph.Add(graph.MatMul(x, W0), b0);
            var pred = graph.Sigmoid(h);
            var cost = graph.ReduceMean(graph.SigmoidCrossEntropyWithLogits(y,h));
            //optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
            // Too many parameters for ApplyAdam, not even sure this is the right function to use. 
            TFOutput var, m = 0, v = 0, beta1_power, beta2_power, lr = 0.01, beta1 = 0.9, beta2 = 0.999, epsilon = 0.00000001, grad;
            var optimizer = graph.ApplyAdam(var, m, v, beta1_power, beta2_power, lr, beta1, beta2, epsilon, grad);
            for (int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++)
                session.GetRunner().Run(
                    inputs: new[] { optimizer },
                    inputValues: new[] { dataX, dataY }
                    );
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What issue you are facing? Just by looking at the code we can not figure out what issue you are facing. You need to provide proper details.

Comment: I try to translate my AdamOptimizer python code into tensorflowsharp
ApplyAdam is closest I can find

but AdamOptimizer only take two parameters but ApplyAdam take 10 parameter.  I do my best to kind of figure out six but don't know how to handle the other four.  

Don't know how to handle beta1_power, beta2_power and guess my cost should be one of var or grad.  and don't know what another on is used for.

Comment: @JosephWu I have the same problem. Did anyone provide you with answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow API doesn't provide optimizer classes yet. So to minimize cost function you should calculate gradients using API and then manually update trainable parameters of your model. Here is an example with separate classes for convinience:

```
class Model : IDisposable
{
    TFSession _session;

    TFGraph _graph;

    TFOutput _input;

    TFOutput _output;

    LinearLayer _y_out;

    TFOutput _cost;

    TFTensor _dataX;

    TFTensor _dataY;

    GradientDescentOptimizer _gradientDescentOptimizer;


    public Model()
    {
        float[,] aX = LoadCsv("dataX.csv");
        float[,] aY = LoadCsv("dataY.csv");
        _dataX = new TFTensor(aX);
        _dataY = new TFTensor(aY);

        _session = new TFSession();

        _graph = _session.Graph;

        _input = _graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.Float);
        _output = _graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.Float);

        _y_out = new LinearLayer(_graph, _input, (int)_dataX.Shape[0], 1);

        cost = _graph.ReduceMean(_graph.SigmoidCrossEntropyWithLogits(_y_out.Result, _output));

        _gradientDescentOptimizer = new GradientDescentOptimizer(_graph, _cost, _y_out.W, _y_out.b);
        _gradientDescentOptimizer.ApplyGradientDescent(_graph);

        var runner = _session.GetRunner();


        runner.AddTarget(_y_out.InitB.Operation);

        runner.Run();
    }

    public void TrainModelIteration()
    {
        var runner = _session.GetRunner();

        runner.AddInput(_input, _dataX);
        runner.AddInput(_output, _dataY);


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            runner.Fetch(_gradientDescentOptimizer.Updates[i]);
        }

        runner.Run();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _graph.Dispose();
        _session.Dispose();
    }
}


class LinearLayer
{
    public TFOutput Result { get; set; }

    public TFOutput W { get; set; }

    public TFOutput b { get; set; }

    public TFOutput InitW { get; set; }

    public TFOutput InitB { get; set; }

    public LinearLayer(TFGraph graph, TFOutput x, int inSize, int outSize)
    {
        var wShape = new TFShape(inSize, outSize);

        W = graph.VariableV2(wShape, TFDataType.Float);

        TFOutput tfOutputWShape = graph.Const(wShape);
        TFOutput initialW = graph.RandomUniform(tfOutputWShape, TFDataType.Float);

        InitW = graph.Assign(W, initialW);


        var bShape = new TFShape(outSize);

        b = graph.VariableV2(bShape, TFDataType.Float);

        TFOutput tfOutputBShape = graph.Const(bShape);
        TFOutput initialB = graph.RandomUniform(tfOutputBShape, TFDataType.Float);

        InitB = graph.Assign(b, initialB);

        var matMul = graph.MatMul(x, W);

        Result = graph.Add(matMul, b);
    }
}


class GradientDescentOptimizer
{
    private TFOutput[] _variables;

    public TFOutput[] Updates { get; set; }

    private TFOutput[] _gradients;

    public GradientDescentOptimizer(TFGraph graph, TFOutput grad, TFOutput w, TFOutput b)
    {
        _variables = new TFOutput[4];

        _variables[0] = w;

        _variables[1] = b;

        _gradients = graph.AddGradients(new TFOutput[] { grad }, new TFOutput[] { w, b });

        Updates = new TFOutput[4];
    }

    public void ApplyGradientDescent(TFGraph graph, float alpha = 0.01f)
    {
        TFOutput tfAlpha = graph.Const(alpha);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Updates[i] = graph.ApplyGradientDescent(_variables[i], tfAlpha, _gradients[i]);
        }
    }
}
```